# Is it possible to render React app into static HTML files as if it was server-rendered

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to pre-render the entire React application into HTML/CSS as if it was server-side rendered?

My use case would be to pre-render a release version of my app and put it on a static file host instead of running Node instances.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Check out next.js or gatsbyjs.

Comment: @HåkenLid, that's what I was looking for, thanks!